# how to change image in imageView on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to change the image in image view on button click but it does not changing. I am using JPG image to load in image View

```
- (IBAction) changeImage:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [tappedButton tag];

    if (selectedIndex==0)
    {
        UIImage *modelimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"compositone.jpg"];
        modelImagewView.image=modelimage; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        UIImage *modelimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"composittwo.jpg"]; 
        modelImagewView.image=modelimage; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an storyboard project? Are you sure you have connect correctly the IBAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format - `modelImagewView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"composittwo.jpg"];`

Also, make sure you have set `tag` numbers properly so that `selectedIndex` is not always 0. At the same time check if you have linked this `IBAction` to the appropriate button.

Comment: how to store those images in an array, and perform the same operation

Comment: @chandru what do you mean array? In this case `image` for a `unbutton` changes on some action.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
- (IBAction) changeImage:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*) sender;

    if (tappedButton.tag==0) 
   {
       modelImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"compositone.jpg"];
   } 
   else 
   { 
       modelImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"composittwo.jpg"];
   }
}
```